# Trying to create an Automator Application to transcode and set Creation time from original file using SetFile command

Tags: shell, automator

I have added the "encode media" service for the compression. I am also using the setfile command (after installing command line tools). I can successfully do this in terminal manually but I am having trouble setting the input and output video file as a variable in shell script.

SetFile -d "$(GetFileInfo -m test.txt)" file.txt

Can anyone point me in the right direction. I have manually added the path of the input and output files that I anticipated and the script works I just have no clue how to assign the input video as a variable (as well as the outputted file).

Comment: What are you doing in the workflow to get the items to pass to the shell script?  The `Run Shell Script` action has a setting to pass the input as arguments.  These input items are from previous actions, so the order would depend on exactly what you are doing.

Comment: If this is for the Mac, add the correct tab, or if it is for visual basic, add that tag. POSIX shell does not provide a `SetFile` or `GetFileInfo` (or any other mixed-case utilities)